# An expression of non-boolean type specified in context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql, wpf, database, visual-studio-2010

An expression of non-boolean type specified in context where a condition is expected when I mouseover the top line see image:

[Sql image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlEX9.png)

```
SELECT Bookings.Date, Bookings.Timebegan, Bookings.Timefinished, Bookings_1.Date, Bookings_1.Timebegan, Bookings_1.Timefinished, 
              Bookings.RoomID, Bookings_1.RoomID
FROM     Bookings,
              Bookings AS Bookings_1
WHERE Not Nz(([Bookings_1].[Timebegan]>=[Bookings].[Timefinished]) Or
  ([Bookings_1].[Timefinished]<=[Bookings].[Timebegan]) Or
  ([Bookings].[RoomID]!=[Bookings_1].[RoomID]) Or
  ([Bookings].[ID]=[Bookings_1].[ID]),False)
ORDER BY Bookings.ID, Bookings_1.ID;
```

Does any one have any idea?

Comment: Are you running your query from MS Access?

Comment: What is Nz? Also, `!=` is not valid SQL.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you are running your query in SQL Server Management Studio. NZ() is a VBA function that checks the parameter for null and replaces with an empty string, or in your case: false. This function does not exist in SQL Server and thus you get your error. Remove NZ and try again.

Comment: Thanks, is there any alternative to Nz in sql and I'll remove the !=

Comment: how would i use this in C# to output a message displaying the date time and the room that clashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice riddle (De Morgan's laws reminder ;] ). Try this:

```
WHERE  
    (
        [Bookings_1].[Timebegan] is NULL
        OR [Bookings].[Timefinished] is NULL
        OR [Bookings_1].[Timefinished] is NULL
        OR [Bookings].[Timebegan] is NULL
        OR [Bookings].[RoomID] is NULL
        OR [Bookings_1].[RoomID] is NULL
        OR [Bookings].[ID] is NULL
        OR [Bookings_1].[ID] is NULL
        OR 
        (
         [Bookings_1].[Timebegan]<[Bookings].[Timefinished]
         AND [Bookings_1].[Timefinished]>[Bookings].[Timebegan] 
         AND [Bookings].[RoomID]=[Bookings_1].[RoomID]
         AND [Bookings].[ID]<>[Bookings_1].[ID]
        )
    )
```